# How to create Column name containing spaces in GCP Bigquery table?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am migrating mssql data into Bigquery using dataflow Jdbc to Bigquery template.

I am creating Table with same in schema in bigquery and then running dataflow pipeline.

But there are some tables in mssql where column name contains spaces (e.g.  Employee Details). How can i create same columns in Bigquery which contains spaces?

Comment: in BigQuery - Fields must contain only letters, numbers, and underscores, start with a letter or underscore, and be at most 128 characters long.

Comment: What could be the solution for my issue then? 
How can i map MSSQL to bigquery columns?

Comment: you can replace space with `_` for example

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant , i am running dataflow tempate which directly migrates data from mssql to bq. I think it will not process the data from "Employee Details" in Mssql    to     "Employee_Details" in Biquery.

Comment: As @MikhailBerlyant said, space is not supported in column name, you need to figure out a consistent way to map mssql column name to bq column name (assuming you will also need to fix query against the table)